# Base Uri From Background Process

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to get the base uri of the current web application while running in a thread?

Keep in mind HttpContext.Current will be null so there is no Request object to play with.

Goal: be able to make web requests to different URLs within your web application from the thread to get the rendered output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing this:

1. Assuming that you are okay with using localhost for the domain, use 
   `"http://localhost" + HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath`
2. If you need the exact domain name and also determine if the application is using https and all that fancy stuff, you need access to HttpRequest itself. In that case, create the base url in the method that creates the thread itself and pass it as parameter to the thread.

```
    string baseUrl = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority 
                      + Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/') + "/";
    ParameterizedThreadStart worker= new ParameterizedThreadStart(MyWorkerMethod);
    new Thread(worker).Start(baseUrl);
```

Comment: Was definitely hoping to get the full URL (domain and protocol).  Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

You could get the domain and protocol part from the IIS ADSI provider, but since there can be many bindings you have to choose one yourself:

```
protected void ListServerBindings()
{
    var ls = new List<string>();
    var ss = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppId.Split('/');
    var e = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://localhost/" + ss[2] + "/" + ss[3]);
    foreach(string s in e.Properties["ServerBindings"])
    {
        ss = s.Split(':');
        ls.Add("http://" + (ss[2].Length == 0 ? "localhost" : ss[2]) + (ss[1] == "80" ? null : ":" + ss[1]) + HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath);
    }
    foreach(string s in e.Properties["SecureBindings"])
    {
        ss = s.Split(':');
        ls.Add("https://" + (ss[2].Length == 0 ? "localhost" : ss[2]) + (ss[1] == "443" ? null : ":" + ss[1]) + HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath);
    }
    Response.Write(string.Join("<br />", ls.ToArray()));
}
```

Comment: From the debugger: AppDomainAppId = "259be8bd"

Comment: This obviously only works in IIS, not in the Visual Studio built-in web server.

Comment: D'OH! Pretend this conversation never happened